# Rigging biological mammal Cell

Tags: animation, rigging

Since i'm currently working on "normal" mammal cellmeshes in blender I've stumble across some basic rigging questions I'm afraid I have no idea how to solve.. First of all I'd like to represent those cells in a nearly perfect spherical shape that deforms while performing things like "eating" (phagocytosis, see also: http://sciencejunior.fr/wp-content/uploads/phagocytose2.png) and moving. I've accomplished a basic movement-simulation through using shape keys (see also:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uuSDGsiEYg), but I honestly think there's got to be a better way using armatures. Does anyone have experience in doing such rigging and can hook me up with some hints, especially regarding the phagocytosis?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oddly specific question title, lol. I can't really help you with your "phagocytosis", but I can tell you that using bones will probably give better results than shape keys in this case. Search YouTube for "blender face rig" to get more ideas of how bones can be used for organic deformations.

Comment: If you'd ask me to animate a cell I would make a string of bones just for when it needs to turn and combine it with shape keys of every extreme shape your cell will have to distort itself into. If there is no turning then I would only use shape keys.